# How do I add myself to bug report?

Tags: bug-reporting, launchpad

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1750973) on Launchpad that describes [exactly what is happening to me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007542/program-sub-menus-dark-gray-on-black-thus-illegible).

How do I add myself to this bug report as it is currently marked as "undecided" importance with no-one assigned to it. It is quite a pain not being able to read the menus.

I am worried that making my own bug report would simply cause it to be marked as a duplicate.

I read [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) and also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs. The "how do I report a bug" link doesn't seem to clearly state what to do if you have the same bug. The ReportingBugs page seems to suggest **not** adding "me too!" to a bug report.

---

**(Edit)**

It has been suggested that this is a duplicate of [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug). My intent was to indicate that the bug affected me also, not to merely subscribe to it and get notifications. The reason was that I wanted the developers to know that the bug affected more than one person.

The [answer by pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013996/425017) was helpful because it described how to indicate that the bug affected me as well.

This had the desirable side-effect of generating this message on the bug report:

> Status changed to 'Confirmed' because the bug affects multiple users.

Comment: I wanted to do more than subscribe (which would just mean getting notifications) so the answer by pomsky which describes how to indicate that it affects me has been helpful.

Comment: if you'd check the answer there, you'd see that it covers both simple subscription and more.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now, right at the bottom. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sure. Though I wonder why you think that voting to close as a duplicate == saying existing answer isn't helpful. That is not the case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to the webpage for the bug report and below the bug-title look for

> This bug affects `%n` person(s). Does this bug affect you?

Click on it and select "*Yes, it affects me*" (you need to be logged in at launchpad).

Additionally, look for

> You are not directly subscribed to this bug's notifications.

at the sidebar at the right. Click there and you'll get the option to subscribe to the bug report (you'll get updates by email).

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is appropriate, or not, to add my screenshots of the issue? It isn't my report directly, however they may clarify the situation.

Comment: @NickGammon Yes, sure, if you think you can provide some info which may help the developers then you're always welcome to post yours.